# Update VM's bridged MAC address with Vagrant

Tags: macos, networking, vagrant

Is it possible to dynamically change the MAC address of a VM, using Vagrant?

My host is MacOsX, my guest is Debian8,
and I want to test the following commands (learning about network):

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

The problem is that the first command (/etc/init.d/networking stop) freezes the ssh terminal, so I can't really go forward (I have to vagrant halt, and up again).
And if I remove the first command, then the networking system automatically assigns an IP address to the VM machine as soon as "ifconfig eth0 up" is executed, which defeats the purpose of testing the "dhclient eth0" command (which is actually the one I would like to test).

I'm aware that one can statically change the MAC address at startup (with config.vm.network "public_network" , :mac => "5CA1AB1E0001" for instance), but that's not what I want to do here.

So is dynamic update of the MAC address in a public network with Vagrant possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run this command from `vagrant ssh` as vagrant will use the NAT (eth0) interface to ssh into the VM so if you shut it down the interface, you're cutting your ssh connection.

If you want to run this command you will need to login to the VM directly from VirtualBox (or VMWare if you use this provider) and you will be able to run this command